# Show message "Loading..." in Highcharts on loading data from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, highcharts

I am using highcharts to create charts on my site, it works fine. how i display "loading" message until the chart loading on my page. data loaded dynamically from rails array object not a url.

Comment: see the code http://jsfiddle.net/c73MQ/1300/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't specified loading option in your highchart configuration. To use `showloading()` you do need to have this configuration defined. It uses some default time duration to show loading screen. here a complete option url http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#loading.hideDuration that might help you.